# Generating a wind vector diagram

Tags: python, vector, matplotlib

I am trying to create a wind vector diagram through which I can visualize the direction and velocity of winds. My raw data consists of 50'000 consecutive measures of wind speed at 1'000 different locations. What would be the best option to create this kind of graph in python? I have looked at quiver() in matplotlib. I am puzzled by the fact that quiver() requires vector size and location. It makes sense, but I don't have that information in my data. Is there a function that I can use to create those vectors, and that I have missed? Are there other, more efficient ways to draw this kind of graphs? Thanks.

Comment: So many downvotes and not a single explaination.

Comment: The reason for the down votes is that this question is a wall of text with no code.

Comment: If you know the wind speed (which I assume include direction + magnitude) at many places (which I assume you know the lat-lon of), then you _have_ all the information you need to feed into quiver (you might need some trig to get it out) for a single time step.  How to deal with the time series depends on what you want to ask.  That is between you and your data ;)

Comment: I have only wind speed (not direction) at many places (lat-lon). I am planning on using the time series to estimate the direction (i.e. where a give wind stream is moving). The information that I do not have is the vector size, which is why I posted the question. Is there any function that does that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you have wind speed (a scalar quantity) and not direction (the vector quantity), quiver is not the right type of plot.  Something more like a [heatmap](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/image_demo.html) is probably what you want, or maybe a [contour plot](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/contourf_demo.html) or just a [scatter plot](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/scatter_masked.html) where you set the color of each disk to the wind velocity.

[Here's](http://janne.aukia.com/kuutio/?p=1213) a nice image done with matplotlib that's a heatplot with contour lines, and looks to be geographical.

One nice thing about the contour plot, is that max gradient will be orthogonal to the iso lines, so it's half way there to calculating the visualizing the forces on the wind.

[image]